# Sorting lines inside brackets in vim

Tags: vim

I would like to sort alphabetically all lines inside brackets (e.g. useful in CSS files)

Right now I'm doing:

`vi{` `:sort` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

But I would prefer something like `si{` (*sort inside brackets*). Any way to achieve that?

**Example:**

Current state (cursor anywhere inside the brackets)

```
.selector {
    width: 100vw;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    color: blue;
}
```

Expected output

```
.selector {    
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: blue;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: use a global command `:g/{/,/}/ sort`

Comment: Thanks for your proposal @LievenKeersmaekers but this doesn't seem equivalent to what I'm doing right now (and it actually broke my CSS file)

Comment: Do you have nested brackets? Perhaps easier to add an example of some section(s) that need sorting.

Comment: No nested brackets (but of course it'd be even better if the solution could handle this situation).

Comment: Well, there's no such thing as nested brackets in CSS.

Comment: You're right @romainl, but if the solution handles nested brackets it could be useful for SCSS and Less.

Comment: @JordiNebot - sorry, forget the offsets. This should work `:g/{/+1,/}/-1 sort`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing the cursor is on the opening `{`:

```
:.+1,/}/-1sort
```

or, using default shortcuts:

```
:+,/}/-sort
```

Supposing the cursor is on the closing `}`:

```
:?{?+1,.-1sort
```

or the shorter:

```
:?{?+,-sort
```

Supposing the cursor is between `{` and `}`:

```
:?{?+1,/}/-1sort
```

or the shorter:

```
:?{?+,/}/-sort
```

You could map the last one like this:

```
nnoremap siB :?{?+,/}/-sort<CR>
```

or create an operator as per `:help :map-operator`.